# Building array from conditions on another array

Tags: arrays, matlab, if-statement, for-loop

I am new to matlab. I want to do the following:

- Generate an array of a thousand replications of a random draws between three alternatives A,B and C, where at every draw, each alternative has the same probability to be picked.

So eventually I need something like P = [ A A B C B B B C A C A C C ... ] where each element in the array was chosen randomly among the three possible outcomes.

I came up with a solution which gives me exactly what I want, namely

```
% Generating random pick among doors 1,2,3, where 1 stands for A, 2 for B,
% 3 for B.

I = rand(1);

if I < 1/3
    PP = 1;
elseif 1/3 <= I & I < 2/3
    PP = 2;
else 
    PP = 3;
end 

% Generating a thousand random picks among dors A,B,C

I = rand(999);

for i=1:999    
if I(i) < 1/3
    P = 1;
elseif 1/3 <= I(i) & I(i) < 2/3
    P = 2;
else 
    P = 3;
end 
PP = [PP  P]
end
```

As I said, it works, but when I run the procedure, it takes a while for what appears to me as a simple task. At the same time, I long such a task is "supposed" to take in matlab. So I have three question:

1. Is this really a slow procedure to generate the desired outcome?
2. If it is, why is this procedure particularly slow?
3. What would be a more effective way to produce the desired outcome?

Comment: not sure I understand exactly what you are doing, but it sounds like you could make an array and use `array(i)=randi(3)` to get what you want. `randi(x)` should give you a random integer on the interval `[0,x)` (Bas Swinckels beat me to it. take a look at his answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done much easier with [`randi`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html)

```
>> PP = randi(3,1,10)
PP =
     2     1     3     3     2     2     2     3     2     1
```

If you actually want to choose between 3 alternatives, you use the output of `randi` directly to index into another matrix.

```
>> options = [13,22,77]
options =
    13    22    77
>> options(randi(3,1,10))
ans =
    22    13    77    13    77    13    22    22    77    13
```

As to the reason why your solution is slow, you do something similar to this:

```
x = [];
for i=1:10
    x = [x i^2]; %size of x grows on every iteration
end
```

This is not very good, since on every iteration, Matlab needs to allocate space for a larger vector `x`. In old versions of Matlab, this lead to quadratic behavior (if you double the size of the problem, it takes 4 times longer). In newer versions, Matlab is smart enough to avoid this problem. It is however still considered nice to *preallocate* space for your array if you know beforehand how big it will be:

```
x = zeros(1,10); % space for x is preallocated. can also use nan() or ones()
for i = 1:length(x)
    x(i) = i^2;
end
```

But in many cases, it is even faster to use *vectorized* code that does not use any for-loops like so:

```
x = (1:10).^2;
```

All 3 solutions give the same result:

```
x =    1     4     9    16    25    36    49    64    81   100
```

Comment: Great to know about space preallocation and randi. Randi is definitely easier. As far as computation time is concerned, once space is preallocated, a variant of the procedure I proposed does a good job too : `% Generating 1000 random pick among doors 1,2,3, where 1 stands for A, 2 for B, 3 for B %


P = zeros(1,1000);
I = rand(1000);

for i=1:1000
    
if I(i) < 1/3
    P(i) = 1;
elseif 1/3 <= I(i) & I(i) < 2/3
    P(i) = 2;
else 
    P(i) = 3;
end 

end`

Comment: The vectorized version of that is: `I = rand(1,1000); P = ones(1,1000); P(1/3 <= I & I < 2/3) = 2; P(I >= 2/3) = 3;`

Answer (score 0):

```
cnt=10;
option={'a','b','c'}
x=option([randi(numel(option),cnt,1)])
```